# HasNoKey in EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I get this error in ASP.NET Core 5 when I run `Add-Migration Category`:

> The entity type 'User' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943. site:stackoverflow.com

This error occurs despite the fact that my `User` entity does have a primary key:

```
namespace UCI.Domain.Entities.Users
{
    public class User: BaseEntity
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        
        public ICollection<UserInRole> userInRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my `Role` entity :

```
namespace UCI.Domain.Entities.Users
{
    public class Role
    {
        public long id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserInRole> UserInRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my `UserInRole` entity:

```
namespace UCI.Domain.Entities.Users
{
    public class UserInRole
    {
        public long id { get; set; }

        // Define the foreign key to associate with the table
        public virtual User User { get; set; }
        public long UserId { get; set; }

        // Define the foreign key to associate with the table
        public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
        public long RoleId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is my database context:

```
namespace UCI.Persistence.Context
{
    public class DataBaseContext : DbContext,IDataBaseContext
    {
        public DataBaseContext(DbContextOptions options):base (options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserInRole> userInRoles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
  
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasIndex(u => u.Email).IsUnique();

            // modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsRemoved);
            // modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsRemoved);
            // modelBuilder.Entity<UserInRole>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsRemoved);
            // modelBuilder.Entity<Category>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsRemoved);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasData(new Role { id = 1, name = nameof(UserRole.Admin) });
            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasData(new Role { id = 2,  name = nameof(UserRole.Oprator) }); 
            modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().HasData(new Role { id = 3, name = nameof(UserRole.Customer) });
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: name the property `Id` or `{Entity}Id` not `id`

Comment: Or decorate your `id` property with the `[Key]` data annotation

Comment: thanks .when i use [key] ,my problem solved but during register user ,my information not registered in database.but change property id to Id solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Rename each id to `Id` or use `[Key]` attribute with each id property

Comment: hi. I have 3 entity(User,Role and UserRole) and I have 1 baseEntity . when i used baseEntity for Role, the application give error that The entity type 'Role' requires a primary key to be defined. your Solution work for User Entity but not work for Role Entity

Comment: Thank you all. My problem has been solved.